# Comparing string from UTF-8 saved CSV file to string in arraylist

Tags: java

I have a CSV file saved as UTF-8. I have a middot in the CSV file that prints as a question mark using System.out. I want to compare it to a string in an arraylist that has a middot. The string in the arraylist is copied from the CSV file and prints out the middot using System.out.

I can't get the strings to equal true using JUnit's assertTrue() because of the middot/question mark.

```
    // Reads from the file using this and adds to an ArrayList
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileSource);

ArrayList<Object> inputData = new ArrayList<>();
String line;

try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            inputData.add(line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}


ArrayList<String> myStrings = new ArrayList<>();

myStrings.add("· Bullet one");
myStrings.add("· Bullet two");
myStrings.add("· Bullet three");

// Comparison uses a for loop
// The inputData is from the CSV file and the expected Data is from the 
myStrings ArrayList
inputData.equals(expectedData)
```

Comment: Add some code! Which libraries are you using to read or parse the CSV file?

Comment: Thanks. It's using BufferReader and InputStream.

Comment: Right, the CSV file has been read, but how is the `ArrayList` populated?

Comment: That is still not enough. A good question includes a minimal example (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the hole thing. And the test case which is failing. Do you use str1==str2 or str1.equals(str2)?

Comment: Updated the description again.

Comment: Could you attach a link to your csv file? At least with one line containing the dot. I was not able to reproduce this problem. The UTF-8 file I created is being properly read and System.out is working fine. Also, make sure your file is really UTF-8. You can open it in on Sublime Text and see the encoding at bottom right.